# How to enable the bootstrap wizard last button

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, wizard

I have used this plugin:
http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/

at last, the next button is becoming is disabled can anyone help how can I enable it.?

Comment: do you want to enable next button after last tab?

Comment: yes i want to enable it

Comment: can you give finish class in last button? or you want to do on next button only? please look at my answer. or it is better if you provide fiddle or some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to use following function:

```
$('#rootwizard .finish').click(function() {
    $('#rootwizard').find("a[href*='tab1']").trigger('click'); // if you want to go to first tab again. Else do what ever you want to do like enable next button again. 
});
```

you have to give finish class in last button.

> Or

you can do like below if you want to do it on next button only:

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
    var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
    var $current = index+1;

    if($total == $current){do what you want on last next button.} }});
```

Answer (score 2):

(Ideally a working snippet with your scenario would be best to help you.)

You could try:

- Removing `.disabled` class from `<li class="next disabled">`

to:

- `<li class="next">`

via jQuery:

```
$('.next').removeClass('.disabled');
```

If JS is overriding it, override it back:

Create an override class such as:

```
.overrideDisabled {
  color: #428bca !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
.overrideDisabled:hover {
  background-color: #eee !important;
  color: #2a6496 !important;
}
```

then via jQuery:

```
$('.next').addClass('.overrideDisabled');
```

Comment: i think `disabled` appending from js so he can't remove it.